# Porting SH1106 Oled Driver - 128 x 64 / 128 x 32 Screen is garbled but partially responsive

Tags: lcd

I'm porting the [SH1106](http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/5e/SH1106.pdf) driver to netmf and have found several libraries that more or less accomplish the same thing. A few were much easier to understand and had less abstraction so I followed those.

I've tried the U8glib with my arduino and it works just fine. The ported display driver yields these results:

[image]
inverted:
[image]

What you're looking at is the screen right after the initialization and attempting to draw a filled circle. You can see the bottom of the circle at the top of the screen. Somehow the origin or page is shifted, but I don't fully understand what's going on. I can send the invert display command and that works as well and turn the display on and off. My initialization code is this:

```c
public void init()
{
    resetPin.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(1); // VDD (3.3V) goes high at start, 
    resetPin.Write(false); // bring reset low
    Thread.Sleep(10); // wait 10ms
    resetPin.Write(true); // bring out of reset

    dcPin.Write(DisplayCommand);

    SendCommandB(0xAE);    /*display off*/

    SendCommandB(0x02);    /*set lower column address*/
    SendCommandB(0x10);    /*set higher column address*/

    SendCommandB(0x41);//0x40);    /*set display start line*/
    SendCommandB(0xB0);    /*set page address*/
    SendCommandB(0x81);    /*contract control*/
    SendCommandB(0x80);//contrast);    /*128*/
    SendCommandB(0xA1);    /*set segment remap*/
    SendCommandB(0xA6);//invertSetting);    /*normal / reverse*/
    SendCommandB(0xA8);    /*multiplex ratio*/
    SendCommandB(0x3F);    /*duty = 1/32*/
    SendCommandB(0xAD);    /*set charge pump enable*/
    SendCommandB(0x8B);     /*external VCC   */
    SendCommandB(0x30);    // | Vpp);    /*0X30---0X33  set VPP   9V liangdu!!!!*/
    SendCommandB(0xC8);    /*Com scan direction*/
    SendCommandB(0xD3);    /*set display offset*/
    SendCommandB(0x00);   /*   0x20  */
    SendCommandB(0xD5);    /*set osc division*/
    SendCommandB(0x80);
    SendCommandB(0xD9);    /*set pre-charge period*/
    SendCommandB(0x1F);    /*0x22*/
    SendCommandB(0xDA);    /*set COM pins*/
    SendCommandB(0x12);
    SendCommandB(0xDB);    /*set vcomh*/
    SendCommandB(0x40);
    SendCommandB(0xAF);    /*display ON*/

    // Switch to 'data' mode
    dcPin.Write(Data);
    this.ClearScreen();
    this.Refresh();

}
```

I have two methods to "refreshing"

```c
public virtual void Refresh()
        {
            Spi.Write(displayBuffer);
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send buffer to display
    /// </summary>

public void Display()
        {
            //set column address
            dcPin.Write(DisplayCommand);
            SendCommandB(0x21);
            SendCommandB(0);
            SendCommandB((byte)(Width - 1));

            //set page address
            SendCommandB(0x22);
            SendCommandB(0);
            SendCommandB((byte)(_pages - 1));
            dcPin.Write(Data);

            //Spi.Write(displayBuffer);

            for (ushort i = 0; i < displayBuffer.Length; i = (ushort)(i + 16))
            {
                //Spi.Write(displayBuffer);
                SendArray(displayBuffer, i, (ushort)(i + 16));
            }
        }
```

At this point I'm a little lost. My hunch is something to do with paging and or display RAM. I'm looking for some insight here on how to fix this as I know there's a lot of experience here with these displays. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's clipped. You are placing the content to high on the screen so only the bottom is visible.

Comment: @Gerben yea, something like that. There's a strip only about 1/8 the height of the display. Know how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your initialization routine looks fine to me (comparing to the datasheet and as evidenced by the fact the display turns on), what doesn't look right is your drawing routine:

```
//set column address
dcPin.Write(DisplayCommand);
SendCommandB(0x21);
SendCommandB(0);
SendCommandB((byte)(Width - 1));

//set page address
SendCommandB(0x22);
SendCommandB(0);
SendCommandB((byte)(_pages - 1));
```

The commands 0x21 and 0x22 don't correspond to any commands I can see in the datasheet.  They look more like commands more commonly seen with ILIxxxx or SSDxxxx screens to create an "addressable window" from 0,0 to Width-1, _pages-1.

Instead you should be using the same commands you used in the setup routine to set the current col / page coordinate in RAM to write to.

Commands `(0x00 | (col & 0x0F))` and `(0x10 | (col >> 4))` set the column position, and `(0xB0 | (page & 0x0F))` set the page number.

You then write all 128 bytes for the current page before moving on to the next page.  This means you will have to do it a page at a time, something like:

```
for (ushort page = 0; page < 4; page++) {

    // Set the current RAM pointer to the start of the currently
    // selected page.
    dcPin.Write(DisplayCommand);
    sendCommandB(0x00); // Set column number 0 (low nibble)
    sendCommandB(0x10); // Set column number 0 (high nibble)
    sendCommandB(0xB0 | (page & 0x0F)); // Set page number

    // Send a single page (128 bytes) of data.
    // Without knowing the rest of your program I don't know the right
    // data sending routines to use, so I made them up. Change it to
    // do it how your program expects.  Maybe with your SendArray
    // function.

    dcPin.Write(DisplayData);
    for (ushort col = 0; col < 128; col++) {
        sendDataB(displayBuffer[page * 128 + col]);
    }
}
```

Note that this method is very similar to how the KS0108 GLCD drivers work.  Each byte of the page represents 8 pixels on the screen so the screen, at 32 pixels high, is split into 4 pages, where each page is 8 pixels, or one byte, high.

The effect you are currently seeing is because you are never changing the current page number (0) so you are always writing your data to the first page.  This loops around multiple times, so you end up writing all 4 pages to the same strip of the display ending up with the last page being displayed, which is the last 8 lines of your display data.  The rest of the display is never being touched and just contains whatever random data was in the RAM at power-on.

Comment: This is a great start. You've confirmed my suspicion and clarified the functionality and the issue. For some reason, I thought the datasheet mentioned that pages will auto-increment when it overflows. Am I wrong? There are still a couple of kinks...The current display I have has 8 pages so I made that change and I'm getting [something that's working](http://i.imgur.com/iEEYHuS.png). I have to figure out the shifting of the start column by 2 as this driver is for 132 columns. Also, the "Hello" should be at the top left.

Comment: Just send 0x02 0x10 instead of 0x00 0x10 to start on column 2 instead of column 0. The page never changes. In the DS it states: "When the microprocessor repeats to access to the display RAM, the column address counter is incremented during each access until address 131 is accessed. **The page address is not changed during this time.**". The location of your "Hello" will be due to where you are telling it to print it since it is drawn in the display buffer not on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought..That's from the initialization too. I found the issue with the text too... Regarding the display buffer versus writing directly to the screen. I would still need to increment the pages with direct writes, correct?

Comment: @GisMofx Correct.  Unless you manually increment the page the display writes will just loop through the current page over and over again - which is what you saw before where it was stuck on page 0.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything else I should be aware of regarding paging/incrementing while I'm developing some methods for this display?

Comment: I always use a framebuffer to store the data locally and output the whole display page in one operation when working with displays of this kind.  It is so much simpler than manipulating the display's RAM.  As long as you do that then there's minimal code for working with the display and everything else becomes completely display agnostic. I recommend sticking to that same approach.

Comment: Thanks. I was deliberating over the two approaches. I really appreciate your feedback and help!